# Getting joint state value given joint name in C++

Tags: ros, c++, joint-states

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say the /joint_states topic published by [joint_state_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/joint_state_publisher) has several joint states:

```
header: 
  seq: 2855
  stamp: 
    secs: 1347822047
    nsecs: 978094100
  frame_id: ''
name: ['ptu_pan_joint', 'ptu_tilt_joint']
position: [-0.4972690939903259, -0.20195947587490082]
velocity: []
effort: []
```

I just want to know the position of 'ptu_pan_joint'. How can I get it in C++ code? For now I am using the following:

```
vector<string> joint_names = joint_state->name;
pan_position_ = joint_state->position[find (joint_names.begin(),joint_names.end(), string(PAN_JOINT)) - joint_names.begin()];
```

Is there a cleaner solution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43924/getting-joint-state-value-given-joint-name-in-c++/) by [aecins](https://answers.ros.org/users/1744/aecins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2012-09-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think there is any cleaner solution for that. I would just not copy `joint_state->name` to a separate variable but would directly reference it or use a reference to avoid copying it. But that's really just a minor thing.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aecins](https://answers.ros.org/users/1744/aecins/) on 2012-09-18**:
I see. Yes, copying to a variable is not necessary at all. Thanks for the info.